# Logic correct for showing that integral of sin(1/x)/x cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

We know that $\int \frac{sin\frac{1}{x}}{x}$  cannot be expressed as in terms of elementary functions. Can the reason be given as like this :

> Suppose it was integrable then we would have the derivative to be discontinuous at x=0 [limit doesnt exist there ] but we know that derivative of a function always follows intermediate value theorem hence there cannot be any jumps in the derivative , hence the function antiderivative doesnt exist ?

Comment: Bad reason. First, the fonction $x \mapsto \sin(1/x)/x$ does not « jump » at $0$. Every real number is a limit point of $\sin(1/x)/x$ tends to $0$.

Comment: also, there's polynomial approximation based on taylor series for every function which you can sample at locations x=[1,2,3,...]... Whle the taylor series can be infinite in length, if the function behaves badly, usually it'll be good enough for normal physics calculations even with few first terms of the  series.

Comment: Moreover, have primitives on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ and on $\mathbb{R}_+^-$ since the function is contiunous on these intervals.